# Simple working Example of json.net in VB.net

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization, json.net

I have the following simplified JSON string from a provider,  its been a long time since I used Visual Studio and vb.Net,  so I'm very rusty!

```
{
"Venue": {
    "ID": 3145,
    "Name": "Big Venue, Clapton",
    "NameWithTown": "Big Venue, Clapton, London",
    "NameWithDestination": "Big Venue, Clapton, London",
    "ListingType": "A",
    "Address": {
        "Address1": "Clapton Raod",
        "Address2": "",
        "Town": "Clapton",
        "County": "Greater London",
        "Postcode": "PO1 1ST",
        "Country": "United Kingdom",
        "Region": "Europe"
    },
    "ResponseStatus": {
        "ErrorCode": "200",
        "Message": "OK"
    }
}
}
```

I want to use JSON.Net to turn this in to something I can work with,  I have read examples etc and JSON.net looks like the answer,  but I'm getting no where.

My .Net code (Me.TextBox1.Text contains the JSON shown above)

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim obj As JSON_result
    obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JSON_result)(Me.TextBox1.Text)

    MsgBox(obj.ID)
End Sub
End Class

Public Class JSON_result
    Public ID As Integer
    Public Name As String
    Public NameWithTown As String
    Public NameWithDestination As String
    Public ListingType As String
 End Class
```

Can someone explain why obj.ID always ends up as 0 please,  and why none of the other properties of my class are populated and what I need to do to fix this, no errors are reported.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your class `JSON_result` does not match your JSON string. Note how the object `JSON_result` is going to represent is wrapped in another property named `"Venue"`.

So either create a class for that, e.g.:

```
Public Class Container
    Public Venue As JSON_result
End Class

Public Class JSON_result
    Public ID As Integer
    Public Name As String
    Public NameWithTown As String
    Public NameWithDestination As String
    Public ListingType As String
End Class

Dim obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Container)(...your_json...)
```

or change your JSON string to

```
{
    "ID": 3145,
    "Name": "Big Venue, Clapton",
    "NameWithTown": "Big Venue, Clapton, London",
    "NameWithDestination": "Big Venue, Clapton, London",
    "ListingType": "A",
    "Address": {
        "Address1": "Clapton Raod",
        "Address2": "",
        "Town": "Clapton",
        "County": "Greater London",
        "Postcode": "PO1 1ST",
        "Country": "United Kingdom",
        "Region": "Europe"
    },
    "ResponseStatus": {
        "ErrorCode": "200",
        "Message": "OK"
    }
}
```

or use e.g. a `ContractResolver` to parse the JSON string.

Comment: I use this site http://jsonutils.com/ to auto create classes for JSON strings to speed things up a bit. Thought I'd mention it for others.

Comment: There's also a VS plug in from Microsoft IIRC in some ASP.Net tool package but I forgot the name...

Comment: @mikro, Thank you for the link. That is going to come in very handy. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 26):

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Dim json As JObject = JObject.Parse(Me.TextBox1.Text)
MsgBox(json.SelectToken("Venue").SelectToken("ID"))
```

Comment: You can install Newtonsoft from NuGet Package Manager. In VB 2019, you can find it in Tools - NuGet Package Manager - Manage NuGet Packages for Solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Place of using this

```
MsgBox(json.SelectToken("Venue").SelectToken("ID"))
```

You can also use

```
MsgBox(json.SelectToken("Venue.ID"))
```