# How to deserialize JSON structure?

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, serialization

I am getting an information formatted as this

```
  {"UFs":   [
     {
     "Valor": "24.184,92",
     "Fecha": "2014-10-07"
     }
   ]}
```

I want to get access to the value and date shown here.

I have got a class

```
Public Class clValores
    Private pTipoValores As String
    Private pValores As String
    Public Property Fecha() As String
        Get
            Return pTipoValores
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            pTipoValores = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Valor() As String
        Get
            Return pValores
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            pValores = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

And this code

```
Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("http://api.sbif.cl/api-sbifv3/recursos_api/uf?apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&formato=JSON")

Dim Valor As clValores = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of clValores)(result)

Response.Write(Valor.Fecha)
Response.Write(Valor.Valor)
```

But when running the code Valor is nothing. What am I missing

Answer (score 0):

from what i read in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21676708/simple-working-example-of-json-net-in-vb-net), it would be as easy as simply wrapping the UFs parameter as well, so to creata an extra class containing

```
Public Class UFsContainer
    public UFs as List(Of clValores)
End Class
```

and then deserialize it with the new class, instead of the clValores

Comment: I tried it this way  Dim Valor As UFsContainer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of UFsContainer)(result) but I didn't get anything

Comment: sorry, i just saw that the clValores is an Array, so it should rather be a List(Of clValores) to deserialize it properly

Answer (score 0):

Add `Imports System.Collections.Generic` to your project and create another class like below -

```
Public Class UFsContainer
    public UFs as List(Of clValores)()
End Class
```

And then deserialize it as -

```
Dim Valor As UFsContainer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of UFsContainer)(result)
```