# JSON (newtonsoft) deserialize using MS Access field names, in VB.net

Tags: json, vb.net, class, serialization

I am trying to deserialize a JSON string which would normally require two classes, I want to substitute one of the classes (see commented out class) with items in an array obtained from MS Access field names.

In this way I wouldn't have to modify my code should the database table change (only the Access table itself and the source JSON).

In my code below, I am stuck on how to define the Public Property "Data" and also the definition of js.data (SampleClass.data). See my ?????? question marks! I am trying to use List (Of String) to store the field names and want to store these lists in Data(0), Data(1), Data(2), etc, so each Data element has the list of field names, and associated values for each record.

I want to obtain my data as follows :
js (SampleClass) contains an unknown number of "Data" lists (according to quantity found in JSON string), each list containing the fieldnames obtained from Access.
I then want to insert the results into the MS Access table with each "Data" list being a record.

Note: I have replaced what would be "rawresp" (from HTTP request) with a very small extract of the JSON string.

Can anyone help please, it'd be much appreciated. I hope this all makes a little bit of sense

Thanks,
Adrian

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

'link to create classes
'http://www.httputility.net/json-to-csharp-vb-typescript-class.aspx
'example of json script
'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21676708/simple-working-example-of-json-    net-in-vb-net

'Public Class Datum
'Public ABC As String
'Public DEF As String
'Public GHI As Integer
'Public JKL As Integer
'Public MNO As String
'Public PQR As String
'Public STU As String
'Public VWX As String
'Public YZA As String
'Public BCD As Integer
'Public EFG As Integer
'Public HIJ As String
'Public KLM As String
'Public NOP As String
'Public QRS As String

'End Class

Public Class SampleClass
    Public Property Success As Boolean
    ?????? Public Property Data As List(Of String)

End Class


Module JSON
    Sub getjson()

    'Try
    cleanup(Nothing, Nothing)
    Dim daoEngine As New dao.DBEngine, db As dao.Database
    db = daoEngine.OpenDatabase(DBPath)
    Dim rst As dao.Recordset = Nothing
    rst = db.OpenRecordset("tUnit")                                    'open table
    Dim fields(rst.Fields.Count) As String

    For j = 0 To rst.Fields.Count
        fields(j) = rst.Fields(j).Name
    Next

    Dim js As New SampleClass

    ??????  Dim js.data As List(Of js.Data)(fields)


    Dim rawresp As String
    Dim request As Net.HttpWebRequest
    Dim response As Net.HttpWebResponse = Nothing
    Dim reader As IO.StreamReader

    request = DirectCast(Net.WebRequest.Create("http://10.32.27.17/api/endusers"), Net.HttpWebRequest)
    response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), Net.HttpWebResponse)
    reader = New IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
    rawresp = reader.ReadToEnd()

    js = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of SampleClass)("{""success"":true,""data"":[{""ABC"":""Something"",""DEF"":""Other""},{""ABC"":""This"",""DEF"":""That""}]}")

   ?????? For Each i As String In js.Data
        rst.MoveFirst()
        Do While Not rst.EOF                                    'look through to end of table
            If n(rst(i(1)).Value) Like i(1) Then
                For Each j In i
                    rst.Edit()
                    rst(j).Value = j
                    rst.Update()
                Next

            End If
            rst.MoveNext()                                      'move to next record
        Loop
    Next


    cleanup(db, Nothing)

    'Catch ex As Exception
    ' Debug.Print(ex.Message)
    'End Try




    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Thats not valid json

Comment: If you are referring to the extra quotation marks, they are required in a VB net string

Comment: I am well aware.  But if you feed the result to any of the robots it doesnt validate.  Its easy to have too many or too few by creating it that way which results in bad json.  JSON.NET will allow you to rename properties in the deserialized object quite easily though

Comment: paste this
{"success":true,"data":[{"ABC":"Something","DEF":"Other"},{"ABC":"This","DEF":"That"}]}

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't Data just be a `List(of Dictionary(of string, string))`?

So - `Data(0).Item("ABC") = "Something"` ... etc.

Not sure how newtonsoft deserializes though, so this is a classic off-the-cuff stack answer (eg - worth exactly what you paid for it) ;)