# Regex Match Next Whole Line After Successful Match

Tags: regex, vb.net, match

I have lots of lines:

```
"extra": {  
"address": "112 Hart blah blah DC 20510",   
"contact_form": "https://www.blah.html",   
"office": "112 Hart Building"
```

Basically, sometimes there is **not** a "contact_form" line after the "address" line and sometimes there is, but there is always an "address" line.

So, after matching the address line: ("address":\s{1}.*\r?)
I want to match the **next whole line**, whatever it is.  After that I'll figure out if the line is the contact_form line or not.

Thanks!

Comment: If it's Json [use a parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21676708/simple-working-example-of-json-net-in-vb-net) and make your life easier.

Comment: It is Json, and I plan on implementing that some time, but for now I just want to use Regex.

Comment: Please provide example inputs and expected outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're intent on using regex, you could use [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match the line that comes after the address line, something like this:

```
(?m)(?<=("address":.*)\r?\n)^.*$
```

Comment: Great answer, just what I was looking for.  Thanks!