# getting json value with vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net, vb.net-2010

new to this site so please bear with me.

this is the code i use to get json data:

```
response = HttpReq.responsetext
```

this is the response i get:

```
{"status":200,"message":"Order(s) created successfully","data":[{"index":0,"referenceId":"307103f84dc94ee188d1111db0cdad86","orderNumber":"7081035854","shipmentOrderTypeCd":"DELIVER","orderState":"FORWARD"}],"hasError":false}
```

how do i get the referenceId in the following format so that i can use the value to update my database?

```
referenceId = 307103f84dc94ee188d1111db0cdad86
```

all help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You can do string split and fetch the text or you can use Newtonsoft to read the property. refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21677364/443244

Answer (score 0):

This is a common thing where I work, as we deal with JSON from API requests.

By far the easiest IMO is to use JSON.Net.  Here's how to get in NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/

Super easy example:
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

So in your case you'd have a class similar to your response (can do a paste special in VS to make a class automatically from a response)
And then Newtonsoft does the rest like so:

```
Dim orderResponse As Order = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Order)(HttpReq.responsetext)
Console.WriteLine(orderResponse.Data(0).referenceId); //maybe depending on your class you deserialize into
```